# Kernel panic when trying to fix broken packages (Nvidia)

Tags: drivers, apt, 18.04, nvidia, kernel

I tried to install nvidia-driver-430 while I was on nvidia-driver-418, and my computer froze (I'm assuming from a kernel panic due to future information).

*Any* help is welcome, be it about fixing the kernel panic or about how to get my computer working at all again. Also, I can get into my system, but it doesn't use a graphics driver so the quality is extremely low.

I went to recovery mode root and tried fixing broken packages:

```bsh
$ dpkg --configure -a # I'm already root due to being in recovery mode
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.59-041959-generic
Setting up nvidia-dkms-430 (430.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-54-generic
```

I'm sorry about the screenshot, but I tried redirecting and it doesn't seem to redirect kernel panics:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm5zI.jpg

The following is the output of some commands I feel might help you understand my issue (Sorry, looks like markdown doesn't support collapsible sections, so I'm using pastebin):

- [$ sudo apt list --installed | grep vidia](https://pastebin.com/9Wv3Ytk5)
- $ cat /var/log/apt/history.log (I can't do the link because of my reputation, but the pastebin is uJ7r71eY)
- [$ cat /var/log/dpkg.log](https://pastebin.com/v93WnZgN)
- EDIT: Boot and sysctl logs removed, I fixed the issue they had by deleting a stray character from sysctl conf)
- [$ lshw](https://pastebin.com/L1m1QQT5)
- [$ lspci](https://pastebin.com/2dpKq7jv)
- [$ dmesg](https://pastebin.com/RXD4VYT6)

Solutions I've considered but don't work:

- I can't `apt remove nvidia-driver-430` since I get a message `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.'
- I've tried using multiple kernel versions (4.15.0-53-generic, 4.18.0-24-generic, 4.19.59-041959-generic). The first two both have the same issue when trying to fix packages, as mentioned above. They also both have the same error in the boot log (see boot log above). The third one, which is the kernel version I usually use, will not boot; it freezes at "Loading initial ramdisk", and stays there for as long as I've tested (up to ten minutes).
- Switching back to Nouveau and then fixing packages. I can't switch back via terminal because I'd need apt, and when I tried via the GUI my computer froze during the progress bar of installing Nouveau drivers. After the freeze, nothing changes when I try to fix broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`update-initramfs`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-update-initramfs/) on your favorite kernel by logging into console and typing:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/4.19.59-041959-generic
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.19.59-041959-generic
```

As far as logging into the GUI you can try selecting **Recover** mode in the **Advanced Options for Ubuntu** submenu reached from the grub main menu.

**Recovery** mode runs in low resolution and isn't a permanent solution. It allows you to reinstall new drivers and then boot normally.

`rm` is needed as described here: [update-initramfs missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-13-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809947/update-initramfs-missing-lib-modules-4-4-0-13-generic)

Comment: $ update-initramfs -c -k 4.19.59-041949-generic
https://pastebin.com/sz5aH3bT

Also I'm currently doing everything through recovery mode, and I can get to the GUI, but it's not using any driver so it's extremely low quality.

Comment: Would it make sense to uninstall and reinstall with ukuu, or is that just an unnecessary danger?

Comment: Just noticed typo `4.19.59-041949-generic` should be `4.19.59-041959-generic` This was reason for error.

Comment: That one worked! Unfortunately, the boot screen still hangs on "Loading initial ramdisk..." :/

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145535/stuck-on-loading-initial-ramdisk-after-upgrading Along with turning off "quiet splash" in grub.

Answer (score 0):

Very roundabout way of doing it, but it worked!

```bsh
sudo rm -r /usr/src/NVIDIADRIVERVERSIONNAME
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt remove nvidia*
sudo apt install nouveau-firmware
```

It still kernel panics when I try to install nvidia drivers, but I'm done with them, so I don't really care anymore :p